possible to have "supertrait-like" bounds on non-Self types?
If I write this code, I have the nice property that because asdf knows T: Bar, it automatically knows T: Foo as well, and I don't have to repeat it, because Bar: Foo
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}

trait Bar where Self: Foo {}

// works!!
fn asdf<T: Bar>(x: T) { x.foo() }

however, sometimes I want to know that if a type implements a certain trait, then a related type implements a different trait. For example
trait Baz {
    fn baz(&self) {}
}

trait Quux: Sized where Option<Self>: Baz {}
impl<T> Quux for T where Option<T>: Baz {}

// doesn't work!! Even if the body is deleted.
fn hjkl<T: Quux>(x: T) { Some(x).baz() }

by having the where Option<Self>: Baz bound, I'm trying to express that "anywhere I have T: Quux, I also know that Option<T>: Baz". This is analogous to the above case, where "anywhere that I have T: Bar, I also know that T: Baz".
However in practice it works in the opposite direction. Instead of getting Option<T>: Baz for free at use sites (e.g., fn hjkl), I'm required to provide it as an additional bound.
What is going on here, and is there a way to bundle up related constraints in the way that I'm aiming for?
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b280ca1a57e5207bcf20bf880bc7dcc6

I have left a comment on this question here (I should probably post a full answer). Its just not how the Rust compiler reasons about things at the moment.

If we state trait Quux: Sized where Option<Self>: Baz {}, can't we provide impl<T: Quux> Baz for Option<T> { fn baz(&self) {} }?

This is a long-standing limitation in rustc: where clauses are only elaborated for supertraits, and not other things #20671.
Whether you use supertrait syntax or a where clause, the only bounds that are automatically implied are ones of the form Self: ... — not any other on the left side.

A workaround is to try to express your problem in a way which doesn't have any of those bounds. For example, we can add a function to Quux:
trait Baz {
    fn baz(&self) {}
}

trait Quux: Sized {
    fn qbaz(value: Option<Self>);
}
impl<T> Quux for T
where
    Option<T>: Baz,
{
    fn qbaz(value: Option<Self>) {
        value.baz()
    }
}

fn hjkl<T: Quux>(x: T) {
    T::qbaz(Some(x))
}

Notice that there is no longer a where bound on trait Quux, and only the implementation of Quux mentions Baz at all. Now hjkl compiles, at the price of needing to use only Quux operations and not Baz operations.
